# Get all users with duplicate email addresses

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a MySQL query where I can get all records from the user table with duplicate email addresses.

This is the query I have so far.. my PHPMyAdmin keeps loading:

```
select personal_email, userid
from user
where personal_email in (
select personal_email
from user
group by personal_email
having count(personal_email) > 1);
```

If I use the query below I get all double emails just once:

```
select personal_email, count(personal_email)
from user
group by personal_email
having count(personal_email) > 1
```

The goal is getting all the records with duplicate emails.

Comment: Your first query should work. The reason it may be slow is that there's no index on `personal_email`.

Comment: Is `personal_email` an indexed field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the query with a JOIN instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT  user.personal_email, user.userid
FROM    user 
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  personal_email
            FROM    User
            GROUP BY personal_email
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) dupe
            ON dupe.personal_email = user.personal_email;
```

MySQL often optimises INNER JOINs much better.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the most efficient way to do this in MySQL is to use an `exists` clause:

```
select u.*
from user u
where exists (select 1
              from user u2
              where u.personal_email = u2.personal_email and
                    u.userid <> u2.userid
             );
```

For optimal performance, create an index on `user(personal_email, userid)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use that result as your selection criteria

```
select * from user where personal_email IN (

   select personal_email
   from user
   group by personal_email
   having count(personal_email) > 1 );
```

A [sqlfiddle for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5687b/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can just join the table to itself on email:

```
select distinct u1.personal_email, u1.userid
from user u1
join user u2 on u2.personal_email = u2.personal_email
    and u2.userid != u1,userid
```

The key to this working is adding `u2.userid != u1,userid` to the join condition to prevent rows from joining to themselves.